# OpenFeint with cocos2d-x (iOS and Android)

Tags: java, android, c++, openfeint, cocos2d-x

Apparently [OpenFeint](http://openfeint.com/) supports both iOS and Android. Great.

But how do I integrate it with cocos2d-x Android? The SDK is, apparently a .jar and such. Cocos2d-x uses c++.

I don't get this tutorial: http://blog.molioapp.com/2011/11/openfeint-and-admob-integrated-with.html

I copy & paste the code and immediately I get errors (JavaVM *gJavaVM;? There is no identifier called that way!)

Are there any other steps not mentioned in that tutorial I missed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  In order to build a C++ library for Android you need to use the NDK.  Getting that set up is pretty involved so I am just going to link you to a separate tutorial that has already covered it.

http://developer.android.com/sdk/ndk/index.html#installing

That is the Google documentation on getting up and running.  There are other resources for this as well if you have trouble.